# Are there any integers numbers, besides 4 and 6, which are both the sum and product of the real integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So, $2+2=2×2=4$, the smallest squared prime number, and $1+2+3=1×2×3=6$, the smallest perfect number. Are there any other real (or hypercomplex) numbers which are both the sum and product of integers? They could be the same, consecutive, nonconsecutive. There is $-x+0+x=-x×0×x=0$, and obviously an infinite variety along those lines. I guess that I'm most interested in situations were there is only one solution. I'd like to know what these numbers are called, and anything of interest which is related. My maths is too rudimentary to know how best to express it, but I'm sure this would be impossible for four or more numbers.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That's not true: e.g. $28$ is perfect but $28\not=1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdot 14$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to create a bunch of these: Take any collection of integers such that their product is larger than their sum. Now include as many $1$s as you need for the sum and the product to become equal. Examples:

- Start with $2,3$, where $2+3<2\cdot 3$. We include one $1$, and now $$1+2+3=1\cdot 2\cdot 3$$
- Start with $3,4$, where $3+4<3\cdot 4$. We include five $1$s and now $$1+1+1+1+1+3+4=1\cdot 1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot3\cdot4$$

If you don't want to use any $1$s this way, because you think it feels like cheating somehow (a feeling I completely understand), then $4=2+2=2\cdot2$ is the one and only example. Products just get too large too quickly for any others to exist.

Any composite number larger than $4$ may be constructed this way, and the ones with a unique solution are the ones that are the product of two (not necessarily distinct) primes.